# How to broadcast the received messages to two different flows

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

How to broadcast the received messages to two different flows

I am using akka stream websocket client to request and receive the data websocket server. 
With the received data from the websocket, I would like to broadcast into two different flows. 
The image below, should clarify the scenario:

[image]

As you can see on the image, it should be broadcasted to two different flows subsequently to seperate sink.

The websocket client can be created as the following:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.Done
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._

import scala.concurrent.Future

object WebSocketClientFlow {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
    // emitted when the stream completes
    val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
      }

    // send this as a message over the WebSocket
    val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

    // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"))

    // the materialized value is a tuple with
    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      outgoing
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
        .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
        .run()

    // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
    // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }

    // in a real application you would not side effect here
    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SinkShape to get the required flow

```
Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(){
  implicit b =>
    val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Message](2))
    val flow1 = b.add(Flow[Message].map(m => m))
    val flow2 = b.add(Flow[Message].map(m => m ))
    val sink1 = b.add(Sink.foreach(println))
    val sink2 = b.add(Sink.foreach(println))

    bcast ~> flow1 ~> sink1
    bcast ~> flow2 ~> sink2

    SinkShape(bcast.in)
})
```

The entire code is

```
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import system.dispatcher

  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes

  val incomingSink = Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
    implicit b =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Message](2))
      val flow1 = b.add(Flow[Message].map(m => m))
      val flow2 = b.add(Flow[Message].map(m => m ))
      val sink1 = b.add(Sink.head[Message])
      val sink2 = b.add(Sink.head[Message])

      bcast ~> flow1 ~> sink1
      bcast ~> flow2 ~> sink2

      SinkShape(bcast.in)
  }).mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future(Done))
  // send this as a message over the WebSocket
  val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

  // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
  val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"))

  // the materialized value is a tuple with
  // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
  // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
  // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
  val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
  outgoing
    .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
    .toMat(incomingSink)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
    .run()

  // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
  // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
  val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
      Future.successful(Done)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
    }
  }

  // in a real application you would not side effect here
  connected.onComplete(println)
  closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
```